# Auto submit form on different page after query string is passed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Is this possible?

So I have the code below on the first page:

```
    <form method="get" action="http://webpage.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="a" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="b" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" name="c" value="3">

        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

And the form fields in the second page are prepoulated with 1, 2, 3. Would it be possible for me to auto-submit this second form on load using code from the first page if the pages are on different domains, or would the auto-submit have to be done from the second page?

I don't see how it would be done, but figured I would ask anyway.

Comment: The auto submit must be done from the second page. Think about what kind of security risks would exists if people could just submit forms on webpages that they did not control!

Comment: Ah, yeah not sure how I didn't think of the security implications. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be possible for me to auto-submit this second form on load using code from the first page

No. Nothing you do on a page can influence the behaviour of the following page (other than by passing data to it that logic *in the subsequent page* triggers on).